# NoStepInto not working in VS 2005

Tags: visual-c++, debugging

I'm running VS2005 and added this entry to my registry:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\8.0\NativeDE\StepOver]
"10"="new=NoStepInto"
```

However pressing F11 still brings into the new-code. What went wrong?

Comment: You don't have any #defines that change 'new' into something else for debugging, by any chance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrong name.  Adding the following keys worked on my machine with VS2008:

```
10 = operator new=NoStepInto
11 = memset=NoStepInto
```